# How to reduce a Ruby hash by a given array of keys?

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a simple way to copy/reduce a hash, but only include the keys/values specified in an array of keys.

```
original_hash = { one: 1, two: 'too', three: 3 }
wanted_keys = [:one, :three]
new_hash = # do something with the hash
expect(new_hash).to eq({ one: 1, three: 3 })
```

Answer (score 8):

If the hash has a very large number of keys and/or the array of wanted keys is very large (improbable as that may be),

```
original_hash.select { |k, v| wanted_keys.include?(k) }
```

would be relatively inefficient because a linear search of `wanted_keys` is required for each of `original_hash`'s keys. Here are two ways to speed things up. (@Lucas' solution is a third way.)

**Convert `wanted_keys` to a set**

```
require 'set'

wanted_keys_set = wanted_keys.to_set
original_hash.select { |k, v| wanted_keys_set.include?(k) }
  #=> {:one=>1, :three=>3}
```

**Match `wanted_keys` with the values of those keys in `original_hash` and then convert the resulting array to a hash**

```
wanted_keys.zip(original_hash.values_at(*wanted_keys)).to_h
  #=> {:one=>1, :three=>3}
```

Prior to Ruby v2.0, when `Array#to_h` made its debut, this would be written

```
Hash[wanted_keys.zip(original_hash.values_at(*wanted_keys))]
```

Comment: The last two should be preferred because they're fastest. Like you said, using `select` and `include` will slow processing as the hash size, or desired key array, grow.

Comment: @theTinMan, thanks for pointing out, "...or desired key array, grow". I added that.

Answer (score 8):

this is for your spec passing :)

`original_hash.slice(*wanted_keys)`

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using Rails, you could use [`Hash#slice`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#slicing)

```
require "active_support/core_ext/hash"

original_hash = { one: 1, two: 'too', three: 3 }
wanted_keys = [:one, :three]
new_hash = original_hash.slice *wanted_keys
#=> {:one=>1, :three=>3}
```

Implementation of `Hash#slice` method is present in Active support core extensions code [rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb)

Answer (score 2):

if you dont wanna to iterate whole `Hash`, you can use [each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
original_hash = {one: 1, two: 'too', three: 3}

wanted_keys = [:one, :three]

# iterate only array of keys
new_hash = wanted_keys.each_with_object({}) do |key, exp|
  exp[key] = original_hash[key] if original_hash[key]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like (inefficient solution below)

```
original_hash.select{|k,v| wanted_keys.include? k }
```

I'm not entirely up on my Ruby-foo so I'm not sure if this returns a list or a Hash.

Comment: It returns a hash.

Comment: What use is an answer when the author states that it may or may not be correct? Do your research before posting an answer! `{}.method(:select).owner #=> Hash` tells you that the method is `Hash#select`. Say your code works because `select` returns a hash, and give the link to the doc: [Hash#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-select). I suggest you edit.